# doctrine2 ORM and naming strategy

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How doctrine has to be configured, to use underscore field name rather than camelCase?
a part of doctrine configuration in my symfony app:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
```

but doctrine:mapping:import generates everything camelCased

```
$qb->select('partial row.{ my_underscored_field })
```

throws "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 344 near 'my_underscored_field =': Error: Class My\Enity\Namespace has no field or association named my_underscored_field"

whilst

```
$qb->select('partial row.{ myUnderscoredField })
```

returns my expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this call:

```
$qb->select('partial row.{ my_underscored_field })
```

`my_underscore_field` is the property of your entity.

The `naming_strategy` is used only for MySQL columns name, not in QueryBuilder or in class definition.

Comment: so, in order to use underscored names in queryBuilder i have to define entity property as my_undersoce_field, am i right?